# console log array item not knowing array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that has items - it is finished, it has it's length but I don't know what exactly length it is. For example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
```

Now I want to console.log every array item like:

```
console.log('test ---> ' + arr[0] + ', ' + arr[1] + ', ' + arr[3] + ' <--- test');
```

But since every time array has different length, and console.log do not accept any sophisticated code in it, I simply do not know how to do that. Any idea?

Comment: well you can log the entire array like `console.log(arr)`. But also if you really want to pass them in as comma-separated arguments, you can just use the spread operator: `console.log(...arr)`

Comment: why can't you use arr.join()?

Comment: @Bryan Dellinger  console.log('test ---> ' + arr.join() + ' <--- test'); - good idea I did not think about join()! [@]Nick - console.log('test ---> ' + ...arr + ' <--- test'); will not work, and it is ES5 code only, but thanks!

Comment: `console.log('test ---> ' + arr.join(', ') + ' <--- test');`

Comment: @Nick this is done by default.

Comment: Not with the spaces!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
console.log("test ---> " + arr + " <--- test");
```

Comment: NIce, but via join() I can add some text in between items.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log('test ---> ' + arr.join(", ") + ' <--- test');
```

I won't explain what this does because it's painfully simple.

If you want each one as a new log:

```
arr.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
```

You can use `Array.prototype.join()` method to log the array of any number of items.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```
console.log('test ---> ' + arr.join(', ') + ' <--- test');
```

or you can use `console.table()` to see the table representation of an array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table

```
console.table(arr);
```